# sanitize string to make its content only to plain text

Tags: php

I am designing an basic ecommerce application, where I have a form to add product.

There are 2 text fields: product name, and description.

product name is `input type="text"`, description is `textarea`

As user can input anything (worst case scenario), I want to remove all tags (no matter its PHP, HTML, JS, CSS, anything), so that I get just plain text (w/o any tags)

How can I achieve this?
Basically, I need to sanitize string, so any to make it plain text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to rip out all tags from the user input, then you can use the `strip_tags()` function.

A better option would be to run the user input through [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/). It's a more complete clean.

Comment: I'll definitely add that one to my arsenal when "heavy weaponry" is needed - that looks like a great library!

Comment: I think if no he needs no HTML tags for text formating then he can just use htmlspecialchars() for the output. An it should be enough.

Comment: This keeps `&nbsp;` and `"/\r|\n/"` .. see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757671/how-to-remove-line-breaks-no-characters-from-the-string) to remove those..

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the strip_tags function, perhaps try something like this:

```
$cleaner_input = trim(strip_tags($input)); // trim is there for good measure
```

Make sure that you're also handling [magic quotes](http://php.net/magic_quotes), otherwise actual quote characters can become a problem and get backslashes before them (they are being depreciated but are still relevant in most hosting environments).

Keep in mind that strip_tags will keep text between tags, so would be somewhat of a problem for JavaScript/CSS but at least the browser will render it as pure text. Give a preview to the user that is entering the data and they will see that they messed up.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way.
For versions of `php<5.2.0` when we have to validate or filter user data, we normally use regex and/or  complex php functions. 
Some of those regex are difficult to understand/remember. So normally most of the coders search in google to collect the correct regex.

For `php>=5.2.0` you can use `filter_var`.

Comment: second link is broken