# Saving line breaks with preg_replace

Tags: php

I have this code for saving line breaks in text area input to database:

```
$input = preg_replace("/(\n)+/m", '\n', $input);
```

On examining the input in the database, the line breaks are actually saved.
But the problem is when I want to echo it out, the line breaks do not appear
in the output, how do I preserve the line breaks in input and also echo them
out. I don't want to use `<pre></pre>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove line breaks (no characters!) from the string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757671/how-to-remove-line-breaks-no-characters-from-the-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are replacing actual sequences of newlines in the `$input` with the literal two character sequence `\n` (backslash + n) - not a newline. These need to be converted back to newlines when read from the database. Although I suspect you intend to keep these actual newlines in the database and should be using a double quoted string instead...

```
$input = preg_replace('/(\n)+/m', "\n", $input);
```

Note that I have replaced the first string delimiters with single quotes and the second string with double quotes. `\n` is a special sequence in a regular expression to indicate a newline (ASCII 10), but it is also a character escape in PHP to indicate the same - the two can sometimes conflict.

Comment: You are correct, I found out, I had to convert back the output to new lines. I used the following code and it worked:  $output = preg_replace("/(\n)+/m", '<br>', $output);

Answer (score 3):

I think PHP has the solution:

> [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) — Inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string

**Edit:** You may need to replace CR / LF to make it work properly.

```
// Convert line endings to Unix style (NL)
$input = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r"), "\n", $input);

// Remove multiple lines
$input = preg_replace("/(\n)+/m", '\n', $input);

// Print formatted text
echo nl2br($input);
```

Comment: Thanks, the issue with nl2br is that it doesn't work if the input is copied and pasted into the text area instead of typing directly and hitting the enter key.

Comment: I think you need to clear CRLF. Please take a look at my edit.