# Get Rid of linebreaks in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to save a html code

```
<p>fasdfasdf</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

when i save it in mysql it is save like this also

```
<p>fasdfasdf</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

how can i get rid of all line break so it will save like this

```
<p>fasdfasdf</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing line breaks (no characters!) from string retrieved from database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757671/removing-line-breaks-no-characters-from-string-retrieved-from-database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily remove all new lines ("\n") by using php's str_replace function:

```
$clean_string = str_replace("\n", "", $html_code);
```

For more info look at the following: http://php.net/str_replace.

Hope that helps!