# PHP NL2BR effect not as expected

Tags: php, jquery, nl2br

I have a strange issue here, can anyone tell me why my nl2br does not seem to be achieving the desired effect?

Here's the screenshot of the data as stored in mysql phpmyadmin:
[image]

Here's a screenshot of my source code jquery / php code to display the data in a text area:
[image]

Here's a screenshot of the resulting jquery code which results in a **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL** error, i suspect its because of the carriage return in the actual source code. 
[image]

I've tried it without nl2br, all it does is create the same output (website source code) but without the HTML break tag.
Both ways it seems to create the "carriage return " in the javascript code itself.

What am i missing here? Something missing with my source data or code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove line breaks (no characters!) from the string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757671/how-to-remove-line-breaks-no-characters-from-the-string)

Answer (score 3):

> nl2br — Inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string

It doesn't replace newlines, it just adds a line break.  If you need to remove them, you have to use something like `str_replace`

```
str_replace( "\n", '<br />', $text );
```

Or to make sure you get all variants of a newline:

```
str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "<br />", $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: 
[Pass a PHP string to a JavaScript variable (and escape newlines)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-and-escape-newlines)

Which tells us to json_decode($phpvariable) to make it javascript friendly