# New line string "\n" not being recorgnized by nl2br

Tags: php

I have a string which is returned by a web service and contains the new line characters, "\n". When I try to output the string with the [nl2br](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function, the string is returned as is, with "\n" inside the string.

Could it be possible that the new line character needs to have some special encoding to be identified as such or am I missing something trivial here?

Hex representation of the input string

```
48617570747374726173736520315c6e416e737072656368706172746e65723a204d6178204d75737465726d616e6e
```

Comment: Maybe it's literal `\n` string sequence instead of New Line character?

Comment: `nl2br` will add the `br` and it will also _keep_ the original new lines. Is that the issue?

Comment: May we look at hex representation of this string? (bin2hex)

Comment: @Justinas, you may be right about it being a literal string sequence. The new line sequence is correctly displayed when I edit the string.

Comment: @SalmanA No, that is not the problem. The whole string is treated as if no lines were present.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove line breaks (no characters!) from the string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757671/how-to-remove-line-breaks-no-characters-from-the-string)

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the other other question. My problem was that I had a literal `\n` string sequence while that other question was trying to convert actual line breaks. The problem the OP for the other question had was the fact that `nl2br()` adds a `<br />` tag to the line breaks while my problem was that `nl2br()` did not change the string at all due to the literal `\n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
48617570747374726173736520315c6e416e737072656368706172746e65723a204d6178204d75737465726d616e6e
```

According to your hex string it seems that your string does not contain newline. It just `\n` - two bytes `5c6e` where `5c` is `\` and `6e` is `n`. But new line is `0a`

```
echo (bin2hex("\n")); // 0a
```

You could replace `\n` with `<br />` using `str_replace`.

```
$string = hex2bin('48617570747374726173736520315c6e416e737072656368706172746e65723a204d6178204d75737465726d616e6e');
echo str_replace('\n', "<br/>\n", $string);
// please note, that '\n' and "\n" are different in PHP, '\n' - just two symbols, "\n" - one new line symbol.
```

Some code: http://3v4l.org/N0FjC#v540

Answer (score 1):

to replace all linebreaks to br tag
the best solution is:

```
<?php 
function nl2br2($string) { 
$string = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "<br />", $string); 
return $string; 
} 
?>
```

because each OS have different ASCII chars for line-break:

```
windows = \r\n 
unix = \n 
mac = \r
```

Comment: ... Or replace your array with `PHP_EOL`.

Comment: This could be a possible solution, what however puzzles me is the reason why the character is not recorgnized by the original nl2br function.

Answer (score 0):

> nl2br — Inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string

It doesn't replace newlines with line breaks, it inserts it before.

Comment: It does neither  in this case, the string is printed out without any HTML line breaks at all.

Comment: Sorry about that. Are you outputting the string in the browser or in the console? Check that it's not being html encoded by looking at the browser source.