# PHP remove all linefeeds/spaces between table tags

Tags: php, regex, html-table

I'm trying to remove all spaces and linefeeds between tables tags (< table >, < tr >, < td > etc) from a string, as those spaces usually create a mess when the string is echoed with php).

Here is my first attempt :

```
$pattern_table = '(<table.*</table>)';
$string = preg_replace_callback('~'.$pattern_table.'~isU', "replace_tbl_lf", $string);

function replace_tbl_lf($match) {
        list($contenu) = $match;   // regex match groups
        $content= preg_replace("/\r|\n/", "", $content);
        $content= preg_replace("/>\s+</", "><", $content);
        return $content;
}
```

This is not 100% efficient : tables are not too distorted as far as I can see, but there is still a serie of linefeeds BEFORE the tables.

Comment: Try `(\s*<table.*</table>\s*)` so you get the leading and trailing whitespace as well. Whitespace shouldn't be affecting your rendered HTML though..

Comment: if spaces are effecting the rendered HTML something else is going on

Comment: `$content= str_replace("_ _", "_", $content);`  (the _ stay for blanks) this would replace 2 blanks with one everywhere. and this would solve the mess.

Comment: This is about editing web page content in forms with textareas, saved in a database, etc. If I enter all tags without any space or linefeed between them, the tables are rendered correctly, but then it's a real mess to read and modify these tables and data ! at least when tables are big...

Comment: you shouldn't store the HTML in the db, you should store the data and format (with HTML) on output

Comment: This uses str_replace which is faster than preg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757671/how-to-remove-line-breaks-no-characters-from-the-string.

Comment: I need to store some html in the db, as I have not only text, but also images, iframes, and tables in my content...

Comment: The problem is that I get a lot of parasitic linefeeds before the table, coming out of nowhere ! I don't even understand how they are created, is this an internal PHP bug ?