# PHP Remove Unused Line Breaks Using nl2br

Tags: php

How to remove unused line breaks using `nl2br` function for this example:

```
Hello


Nice
```

Expect output display:

```
Hello

Nice
```

and another example:

```
remove this unused line
remove this unused line
remove this unused line
Hello
remove this unused line
remove this unused line
remove this unused line
remove this unused line
```

Expect output display:

```
Hello
```

So means if the line break more than 3 line, so only set 1 line breaks.

Here is my PHP code:

```
nl2br($string);
```

Comment: nl2br() takes the newline character and changes it to a HTML <br>.

Comment: So is it possible to custom the function maybe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove line breaks (no characters!) from the string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757671/how-to-remove-line-breaks-no-characters-from-the-string)

Comment: `preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $yourString );` from related.

Comment: Please have a look at the question, it's different case not same with the link you gave. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old schooled but hope this works

```
$str = explode("\n", $str);

foreach($str as $val){   
    if(!empty($val)){        
       $result[] = $val; 
    }    
}

$final = implode("\n", $result); //if you want line break use "<br>"
echo $final;
```

Comment: tried the code but the display  like this : Hello Nice. What I want is Hello (then give it only 1 <br> Nice like example above

Comment: if you want line break use '<br>' instead  of "\n" when implode. when you use "\n" you can see the new line in viewsource

Comment: Or is this you want? `$final = implode("<br><br>", $result);`