# Why Line Breaks matters when string come from ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, string

I have a php file
`test.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="/jquery.js"> </script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
$.post("/text.php",function(result){ $("body").append(result);});
 });
</script>
</head>
 <body>
</body>
</html>
```

`text.php`

```
hello
far

faar


faar
```

We know  In html, All line breaks and spaces , automatically reduced to single space ,But in this case
  line breaks increasing the space between words[image]

Any ideas ? please

Comment: Is my question is unclear?

Comment: This makes no sense. You should get no line breaks at all - all whitespace is reduced to a single space, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/4raqqo8w/

Comment: did you try that using php @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Makes no difference. HTML is HTML. If the HTML is different when you run it through your AJAX request, check what is being returned from the request in the DOM inspector

Comment: Try it first please

Comment: I can't as I'm not a PHP dev. If that's important to the question the you should have an example for people to view. You shouldn't expect people to run up an instance of your code locally to debug. If someone's willing to help you, then you should be making it as easy for them as possible.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce.](http://temp.dev.redstarfm.com/test.php)

Answer (score 1):

Check the Content-Type header in the network history.

I assume for the text.php it's text/plain, where line breaks are relevant. That's ignored in the first test as the text is appended into HTML DOM.

Comment: did u try it. ?

Answer (score 1):

What you receive from the Ajax call is just plain text. If you append a plain text with jQuery, it will be added as a text node.

You can explicitly turn the plain text to HTML.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $.post("/text.php",function(result){
     $("body").append($(result));      // Notice the $ before result
   });
 });
```

Or you can wrap your text in a `p` or `span` element.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $.post("/text.php",function(result){
     $("body").append($("<p>" + result + "</p>"));      // Notice the $ before result
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this If you want to `remove multiple spaces` from result

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.post("/text.php",function(result){ result=result.replace(/\s+/g, ' '); $("body").append(result);});
});
```

And try this if you want to `keep those as multiple line` as it was in text.php

```
function nl2br(str, is_xhtml) {
     var breakTag = (is_xhtml || typeof is_xhtml === 'undefined') ? '<br />' : '<br>';
     return (str + '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1' + breakTag + '$2');
}    
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.post("/text.php",function(result){ result=nl2br(result); $("body").append(result);});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use trim/rtril or ltrim php function? and for line break see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757671/how-to-remove-line-breaks-no-characters-from-the-string)