# How to access php value with line breaks in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have following variable in php which is contains paragraph with line breaks. i need to put this `$message`value in session and access the session in jquery.

Message from `textarea` look likes:

[image]

```
$message    = nl2br($_POST['message']); 
$_SESSION['message'] = $message;
```

So when i access paragraph with line breaks it not working, but paragraph with out line breaks, it works. What the error here?

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
  $(document).ready(function () {
     var subject = "<?php if(isset($_SESSION['subject'])){echo $_SESSION['subject'];} ?>"
     alert(subject);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but make sure you sanitise the user input or you are vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Comment: JS strings cannot cross line boundaries. To get this working you'll need to replace the line breaks with `/n` for example. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757671/how-to-remove-line-breaks-no-characters-from-the-string) is basically what you're asking