# Pass unicode php variable to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

I trying to pass `wordpress` posts title and excerpts (which are persian)  to `javascript`. here is code in `.php` script file:

```
function change(){
            document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = '<a href="$links[2]">$titles[2]</a>';
            document.getElementById("exer").innerHTML = '$excerpts[2]';
            document.getElementById("img").innerHTML = '$imgs[2]';
}
```

There is no problem with titles but when I add excerpts, it makes error in `javasripts`.
The generated `javascript` tag in browser is:

```
        function change(){


            document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = '<a href="http://sirsaleh.com/2016/09/21/semi-private-idea/">یک ایده &#8211; حریم نیمه‌خصوصی</a>';
            document.getElementById("exer").innerHTML = '<p>چیزی که می‌خوام بگم با حریم نیمه‌خصوصی‌های تعریف شده در جاهای دیگه، اشتباه گرفته نشه. مطلبی که پیش روی شماست کاملا من‌درآوردی است.  ما همیشه می‌گیم یه چیز خصوصیه و یه چیز عمومیه. داشتم به این فکر می‌کردم، بد نیست با همه چیزای عمومی مثل هم‌رفتار نکنیم! به‌نظرم یه وقتایی به نظرم لازمه یه &hellip; <a href="http://sirsaleh.com/2016/09/21/semi-private-idea/" class="more-link">ادامه خواندن<span class="screen-reader-text"> &#8220;یک ایده &#8211; حریم نیمه‌خصوصی&#8221;</span></a></p>
';
                    document.getElementById("img").innerHTML = '';
    </script>
```

here is the error shown in chrome-browser (it refers to line I passed $excerpts to javascript):

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

When I use `json_encode` in `php` to convert varible for javascript, the errors vanishes, But all of the excerpts variable become empty string `""`.

I tried some `regex` solutions to deleted unwanted non-unicode characters but it has same problem also.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OH! I find out something in the output of `the_excerpt()` function of wordpress. It contains a newline character in the `the_excerpt()` output.
so thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10757755/2454690), I used regex like this:

```
$excerpts = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $excerpts );
```

and problem solved!