# PHP: remove spaces all but not in a particular string

Tags: php

with this code I remove every spaces in a string.

```
public function callback_register_settings_remove_spaces( $input ) {

        // New Input
        $new_input = array();
        $new_input = $input;

        // Sanitize the input actually
        $new_input = preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $new_input);

        // Sanitize the input actually
        $new_input = str_replace(" " , "" , $new_input);

        return $new_input;

    }
```

But, I need to NO REMOVE spaces if in a string exists a substring like this:

```
<script async src
```

So, if initial string is:

```
<script async src="http">Bla.js</script>
<script>window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer;</script>
```

Need to be:

```
<script async src="http">Bla.js</script><script>window.dataLayer=window.dataLayer;</script>
```

And not

```
<scriptasyncsrc="http">Bla.js</script><script>window.dataLayer=window.dataLayer;</script>
```

Thank you

Comment: I don't know the bigger picture, but you might want to NOT remove spaces from strings inside quotation marks.

Comment: I don't know the bigger picture, but you might want to use a DOM parser if you are trying to handle HTML/XML

Comment: As I'm really bad at *regular expressions* I'd do something like `explode` the string with your `$substring` as *delimiter*, then `str_replace` spaces, then loop through the exploded string values and `echo $substring . array[$value]`. But I know it's by far the worst working way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some kind of syntax parser would be good here.

Here's a quick example of one possibility (a very crude one):

```
function minimizeJs($value)
{
    $output = '';

    $i = 0;
    // Iterate thru all TAGs by starting <
    while (($o = strpos($value, '<', $i)) !== false) {
        // There's a match between two TAGs, strip spacing
        if ($i < $o) {
            $output .= preg_replace('/\s+/', '', trim( substr($value, $i, $o - $i) ));
        }
        // Find end of this current TAG (>)
        $i = strpos($value, '>', $o) + 1;
        // Concat the TAG content
        $output .= substr($value, $o, $i - $o);
    }

    return $output;
}
```

This example is for special cases where data begins with a TAG and ends with a TAG. Parsing data before and after matches need to be added if used for other cases.

EDIT: This will explode if JS contains < or >.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the linebreaks then?

EDIT: Ah! Didn't see those spaces near your "="-sign.
For linebreaks this still works. In your case it might not though. Sorry!

```
preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $yourString );
```

[Source on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757671/how-to-remove-line-breaks-no-characters-from-the-string)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `trim()`, see about this here http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.trim.php, u can use `ltrim()` for remove left spaces and `rtrim()` to.