# how can I get the code to be in single line when viewing the source code?

Tags: javascript, forms, zend-framework, zend-form

I'm trying to create a button which dynamically add input and since I'm using Zend framework I use this method to get the input from the Form file : `<?php echo $this->formm->getElement('refA'); ?>`

but I get this error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

and the jquery function for that add button is :

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var j = "<?php echo $this->formm->getElement('refA'); ?>";
    $("#add-more").click(function(){   
        $(".row").append(j);
    });
});
```

and when I click on that error it shows me where I have the error it seems like that it uses:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var j = "<label for="refA" class="optional">Article:</label>
             <select name="refA" id="refA" class="form-control">
               <option value="test1" label="test1">test1</option>
             </select>";
    $("#add-more").click(function(){   
        $(".row").append(j);
    });  
});
```

is it possible to get the code generated in single line so I can make the button to work ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757671/how-to-remove-line-breaks-no-characters-from-the-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by Kyle, you're facing a quoting issue. But, unlike what he said, quotes *inside* PHP tag **must not** be escaped, since they are rendered server side.

This should do the trick:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    $(document).ready(function (){
        var j = '<?php echo  preg_replace("/\r|\n/", "", $this->formm->getElement('refA')); ?>';
        $("#add-more").click(function(){   
            $(".row").append(j);
        });
    });
}
```

**Edit**: looking at your screenshots and other comments, it seems that you are trying to access jQuery (`$`) before loading (I suppose you are loading all the JS dependencies at the end of the layout).
Since you can't use PHP code in JS files, you have two options:

1. You create a JS variable inside your template (`ajouter.phtml`), like `var inputTemplate = <?php echo preg_replace(....);?>;`, and use that variable in your JS file
2. You make sure that *that* JS snippet is executed only when the page has been fully loaded (hence the use of `window.onload = function(){}`

Personally, I'd suggest you the first option. Inserting JS code inside the phtml is conceptually wrong, because if you somehow you decide to not use jQuery anymore, you won't have to go inside all templates to find those snippets.

Comment: Which error are you getting? If you are getting `T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING`, please **check** that you are not escaping `refA` quotes.

Comment: in visual studio I don't get any error but I getting that Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier error

Comment: Can you post the full error with its stack? and show the exact code that is generating that error?

Comment: "full error with its stack", not just the error message.

Comment: plus: "show the exact code that is generating that error"

Comment: this is the code that generating the error " <?php echo $this->formm->getElement('refA'); ?>" because normally this php code generate the form with <label> then <input .... etc and I guess Jquery isn't allowing to use a string with breaklines

Comment: jQuery/JavaScript has nothing to do in this, if you are getting PHP Error. I repeat: can you please post the *full stack* error and the *exact* code that generate it? Because I tested the snippet I gave you, and it works. If I modify the snippet and I escape the quote, I get that error, but with a full stack, so.... Let us help you.

Comment: what is the stack I'm a quite beginner on this sorry ?

Comment: Join this chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199313/how-can-i-get-the-code-to-be-in-single-line-when-viewing-the-source-code

Comment: I should have 20 reputation to chat give me your facebook so we can see the problem

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the error page? and the screenshot of your code.

Comment: for the source code that the screenshot of it : https://imgur.com/QbTktXO / and for the error here is the screenshot : https://imgur.com/PQO2sBM / and where I have the error screenshot : https://imgur.com/UAEB0YN

Comment: The error shown in the screenshot isn't the one you said. You talked about `T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING`, but there you are getting a js error.

Take a look to the edited code.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a quoting issue - the data that PHP is chucking in there has double quotes which keep terminating your string.  Try wrapping it in single quotes - with escapes for refA:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var j = '<?php echo $this->formm->getElement(\'refA\'); ?>';
    $("#add-more").click(function(){   
        $(".row").append(j);
    });
});
```

Ok, after doing some more digging, you need to get those quotes and spaces out before it.  Unfortunately, I'm not a PHP guy - so I'm hoping that the syntax is  right - the idea, is to get the data from refA and store it in $message - then get rid of any spaces and escape any quotes, then echo the value out to be set as 'j':

```
$(document).ready(function (){
   var j = '<?php $message = $this->formm->getElement("refA"); $message = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", addslashes($message));echo $message?>'
   $("#add-more").click(function(){   
       $(".row").append(j);
   });
});
```

PHP methods found here:
https://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/javascript-escape/

Another option that would completely take care of the issue would be to use es6 - template-strings (back-ticks)

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var j = `<?php echo $this->formm->getElement("refA"); ?>`;
    $("#add-more").click(function(){   
        $(".row").append(j);
    });
});
```

most modern browsers will nativity handle es6 
[Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: I tried it but it shows me this on visual studio code : syntax error, unexpected ''refA\'); ?>'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING)

Comment: did you wrap the entire line in single quotes.  then add the \ escape character in front and behind the refA?  from that error it looks like you only escape the second one - as in instead of "refA"  --- switch to \'refA\' - Let me know if that does the trick

Comment: JS code is rendered client side, while PHP is rendered server side. Therefore, the quotes inside PHP **must not** be escaped.

Comment: I tried it but I got this : Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: aren't you using jQuery?

Comment: @Andy yes, he's using jQuery, but more than likely, he's loading it at the end of the page, while this snippet is places in the middle of the content (when jQuery hasn't still be defined)

Comment: @Kyle I really like the solution with template strings. I'm not using JS a lot and this is the first time I see them. I learned something, thanks! :)

Comment: @KhalilElhazmiri -- if this answer worked for you, could you please mark it as an accepted answer?